# How google is connected across internet

Tags: routing, internet, isp

Well, the question is not only for Google, but for other big Internet companies like Amazon or Yahoo.

I know the question can be a bit weird, but I'll try to explain it a bit. Internet is a network made of multiple networks. So first we have networks from Tier 1 Level like Level3, NTT or Telia-Sonera. Then we have ISP that works at Tier 2 level, who pays for connect end users with the entire Internet.

But some large companies have datacenters across the world. How are these connected?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks you don't manage are off-topic.

Comment: Same way as everything else.  With care, planning, and detail.

Comment: I will throw in the term "anycast": http://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two approaches.

One is to make each datacenter (or cluster of datacenters) a separate "network" with it's own IP space (which may be either allocated by a provider or provider independent) and it's own routing and it's own deals (transit and possibly peering) with networks who have a presence in the datacenter's locality. Traffic between the datacenters in different parts of the world would then go via one or more IP transit providers.

The other approach is to rent circuits (which may be dedicated fiber, WDM wavelengths, MPLS links or whatever) between your datacenters and build a network which appears to the rest of the internet as one network. Traffic between your own hosts in different datacenters never leaves your network. Traffic to hosts elsewhere on the internet will obviously flow in and out of your network but possibly not at the same location where it is generated/consumed. This gives you more flexibility on how traffic is routed and makes it easier to move IPs around to different geographical locations but it can work out more expensive, especially if you are small.

I'm pretty sure google takes the second approach.

---

Someone mentioned anycast in a comment on the question. Anycast is possible with both approaches but you have more flexibility with the "one network" approach since the smallest route you can advertise on the internet is generally a /24 while within your own network you can route individual IPs or even route based on information other than the destination IP.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting networking question that you probably partly answered yourself; huge datacentres are globally located in key areas where very  high speed internet is available to the peering hosting companies.

For your research investigate companies such as Akamai and Cloudfront comes to mind. And the new kid on the block Venturebeat.

Technologies used to load balance between the global sites are many (mostly based on Linux I think).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_CloudFront
http://venturebeat.com/2015/12/09/google-cloud-cdn/
www.sanog.org/resources/sanog24/Peering_Update.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)